# How to filter documents in mongodb based on an interval?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, non-relational-database

I have 2 fields on my document:

```
class MyDoc {
   int to;
   int from;
}
```

And I have an array with values as input: [4, 5, 6]

I want to find all documents whereby all the elements in the given array fit between that **to** and **from** interval.

For a single value it would be easy since I can use **lt** and **gt** but how to do it for all the array elements?

Much appreciated.

Comment: can you give example of the result that you want to find, i am not able to understand completely.

Comment: it would be easy if you get maximum and minimum from that input array, min for `from` and max for `to` and simply query `{ from: { $gte: 4 }, to: { $lte: 6 } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using this:

```
// givenArray = [4,5,6]
.find({
    to : { $in: givenArray},
    from: { $in: givenArray}
})
```